# How to filter SharePoint listitems with PnP Core SDK

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, pnp-core-sdk

I'm unable to find a good example of reading sharepoint listitems and filtering on a custom column with the PNP.Core sdk library in C#.

I could filter on Title:

```
                var listItems = await pnpContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList")
                    .Items
                    .Where(x => x.Title == "Foo" )
                    .ToListAsync();
```

But I would need something like this:

```
                var listItems = await pnpContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList")
                    .Items
                    .Where(x => x["Status"] == "Completed" )
                    .ToListAsync();
```

The result api call should look like this (or the corresponding graph api call):
`_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestList')/items/?$filter=Status eq 'Completed'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the documentation,
https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/listitems-intro.html
Maybe you can do this

```
var listItems = await context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList")
    .Items
    .Where(x => x.Values["Status"].ToString() == "Completed")
    .LoadAsync();
```

[image]

Comment: I am kindly following up to see if you have any remaining questions or concerns for this issue. Please feel free to reach us if any questions or concerns you may have. If the answer is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and kindly upvote it.By doing so, it will benefit all community members who are having this similar issue. Your contribution is highly appreciated